# Cant create 2nd textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I'm having problems with this code and I can't figure out why. It works fine the first time through but crashes with a "Parameter is not Valid" error the 2nd time through on this line:

```
Dim tbx As TextBox = New Windows.Forms.TextBox
```

The full code is as follows:

```
Dim tbx As TextBox = New Windows.Forms.TextBox
tbx.Name = tbxName
tbx.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 12)
tbx.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
tbx.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
Using f As Font = tbx.Font
  tbx.Font = New Font(f.FontFamily, 8, FontStyle.Bold)
End Using
tbx.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(xCords, 44)
Select Case tbx.Name
  Case "tbxBulk01" : tbx.Text = Bulk01Label
  Case "tbxBulk02" : tbx.Text = Bulk02Label
End Select
Me.Controls.Add(tbx)
```

Here's the stack trace:

> at System.Drawing.Font.GetHeight(Graphics graphics)
>     at System.Drawing.Font.GetHeight()
>     at System.Drawing.Font.get_Height()
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_FontHeight()
>     at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.get_PreferredHeight()
>     at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.get_DefaultSize()
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor(Boolean autoInstallSyncContext)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase..ctor()
>     at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox..ctor()

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the code surrounding the snippet that you posted. When are you calling this the second time and from where?

Comment: On my main form_load I have a method called WriteControl. For each textbox I need I call this method and pass in the name of the control and the xcoords.

Just removed most of my code and replaced with this.
 WriteControls("picBulk01", "tbxBulk01", 7)
 WriteControls("picBulk02", "tbxBulk02", 68)

Still getting the same error the 2nd time through

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that I create a picture box with this method too but did not include the code for clarity. That portion seems to work fine and will create 2 picture boxes.

Comment: It would help if you could post a minimal sample that compiles and triggers the error.

Comment: Ok simplified version as follows. Still getting the same error on a test project.

Comment: Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CreateControls("tbxName1", 10)
    CreateControls("tbxName2", 30)
  End Sub

Comment: Private Sub CreateControls(ByVal name As String, ByVal xCords As Integer)
    Dim tbx As TextBox = New Windows.Forms.TextBox
    tbx.Name = name
    tbx.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 12)
    tbx.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    tbx.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
    Using f As Font = tbx.Font
      tbx.Font = New Font(f.FontFamily, 8, FontStyle.Bold)
    End Using
    tbx.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(xCords, 44)
    tbx.Text = "Test"
    Me.Controls.Add(tbx)
  End Sub

Comment: Interesting. I just removed the font section and now it seems to work on the test project. Is there a way to dispose the font after creating the textbox?

Comment: You can edit your question to include the sample code. That way it is much easier to read than in the comments. But anyway, seems you found the error: The font object should *not* be disposed as it is needed as long as your text box / form lives. Remove the `Using` clause and the error should be fixed.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for all the help and thanks for the tip on editing original post. My first time here. Thanks again.

Comment: You seem to already have found the problem but just in case you're still not sure how to write it, I'd just do the following `tbx.Font = New Font(tbx.Font.FontFamily, 8, FontStyle.Bold)` you don't need the f variable at all.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but here is my answer.

I suspected the

USING .... END USING section as well.

I have just read that in the feedback too, oh well, never mind.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim xCoords As Integer = 80
        Dim myTextBox As TextBox = New TextBox

        For index As Integer = 1 To 2
            myTextBox = New TextBox
            myTextBox.Name = "MyTextBox" & index.ToString
            myTextBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 12)
            myTextBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
            myTextBox.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
            myTextBox.Font = New System.Drawing.Font(myTextBox.Font.FontFamily, 8, FontStyle.Bold)
            myTextBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(index * xCoords, 44)
            Select Case index
                Case 1 : myTextBox.Text = "Bulk01Label"
                Case 2 : myTextBox.Text = "Bulk02Label"
            End Select
            Me.Controls.Add(myTextBox)
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```